# Sinatra - Why does 404 error block never trigger?

Tags: ruby, exception, error-handling, sinatra

Here is a simple app:

```
class App < Sinatra::Base
    set :show_exceptions, false

    not_found do
       slim :err_404
    end

    post "/doit" do
        user ||= User.find(params["userid"]) || halt(404)
    end
end
```

When given an invalid userid, the 404 error block should trigger and then render the 404 page. Instead, Sinatra shows "`Internal Server Error`" on the page, and this stacktrace is printed to console:

```
Problem:
  Document(s) not found for class User with id(s) 53d06a8ca7b7d52d11300003.
Summary:
       ....
```

I'm guessing the `halt(404)` isn't being called. I was following this [blog post about error handling](http://myronmars.to/n/dev-blog/2012/01/why-sinatras-halt-is-awesome), so why wouldn't the same thing work here?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using ActiveRecord, `User.find(params["userid"])` will raise an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` exception if there is no matching record. This exception is thrown before the 404 handler gets to run and ends the route handling, resulting in the internal server error.

To fix it you could check for the exception, and call the 404 handler if it is raised:

```
post "/doit" do
  begin
    user ||= User.find(params["userid"]
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    halt(404)
  end
end
```

A better solution might be to use `find_by_id` instead, which avoids using exceptions for flow control:

```
post "/doit" do
    user ||= User.find_by_id(params["userid"]) || halt(404)
end
```